# They have been doctors. [Where to put 'both'?]

Tags: quantifiers, adverb-placement

In order to express the same meaning as "Both of them have been doctors," are these grammatical?

> (1) They **both** have been doctors.
>
> (2) They have **both** been doctors.
>
> (3) They have been **both** doctors.

If these are grammatical, which is the most natural?

Comment: Are they still doctors? This implies that they are no longer doctors.

Answer (score 1):

The quantifiers **all**, **both** and **each** are allowed to float: [this document](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Quantifier-Floating.htm) explains the rules, however it does not clarify the position for present perfect simple of **be**: in my opinion if follows the **all other verbs** rule, namely:

> In sentences with other verbs, the [subject] quantifier cannot move over the verb. The restriction against moving across nonfinite verb forms holds for all verbs

In your sentences, **both** qualifies the subject **they**, so it must be before the verb **been**: this is true for sentences 1 and 2. Of these, I would prefer sentence 2.

Sentence 3 is only valid if **both** qualifies the object. This would be true if they have been something else as well, for example Michael Palin and Graham Chapman trained as doctors and then became actors:

> They have been both doctors and actors

**be** in the present tense is an exception, and all sentences would be valid: note that 1 and 2 convert to the same form in the present tense, as the verb becomes a single word.
I have added an "option zero" as well. In my opinion, sentences 0 and 3 would be better.

> 0) Both of them are doctors.
>   1/2) They both are doctors.
>   3) They are both doctors.

Comment: How about "They could have been both doctors"? Can it ever mean "Both of them could have been doctors"?

Comment: No, it could not. You could only use it in a sentence like "They could have been both doctors and actors."